# lower bound of closed geodesic length in terms of sectional curvature

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a compact complete Riemannian manifold and $l$ be infimum of lengths of closed geodesics in $M$, suppose the maximal of the sectional curvature of $M$ is $K$, could we get a lower bound of $l$ in terms of K?

I think maybe one could apply Rauch's comparison theorem to get such kind of bound but I am not sure how to use that. Thank you so much.

Comment: No. Flat torus. That’s a good example to check whenever trying to do something under the assumption of bounded sectional curvature.

Comment: I just wanted to add that Deane's example can be promoted to one which works if $M>0$.  Namely, consider $S^2\times S^1$ (Riemannian product) where both $S^2$ and $S^1$ have a tiny radius.  You can even generalize this to have a large diameter by looking at $S^2\times S^1\times S^1$ with the last $S^1$ really big.

Comment: @Deane@Jason DeVito
Thank you so much for your comments.